# How does the phase factor change after measurement?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, eigenvalue, quantum-measurements

Suppose that we have a nondegenerate quantum system with an orthonormal basis of eigenstates $|\psi_n\rangle$ with eigenvalues $E_n$. Consider a wavefunction $\psi(x,t)=\sum_n c_n|\psi_n(x,t)\rangle$. Suppose that we measure the energy at time $T$ and obtain value $E_m$. Now the system collapses to the eigenstate $|\psi_m\rangle$. However, what will be the new phase factor? The new wavefunction must be equal to $$A|\psi_m\rangle$$ for some complex number $A$ with $|A|=1$. Is there a rule to determine the value of $A$? With a `rule', I mean a mathematical formula with the numbers $c_n$ and the physical properties of the system as input and $A$ as output.

Answer (score 1):

If the measurement measures phase, e.g., using a kind of [Aharonov-Bohm device](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9709022), then the phase constitutes a quantum number in the spectrum of the measurement operator - that is, in the process of measurement we project the wave function on a state with a specific phase (usually known up to an additive constant).

Otherwise the phase is not relevant (not determined), as it will not influence the results of measurement.

Comment: Maybe the phase is relevant for future measurements: for example, if there will be another particle which will interfere with the particle in the future, then the phase determines how the particles will interact (amplify or cancel out).

Comment: I am interested in the case where the measurement is of energy, not of phase.

Comment: @Riemann For subsequent measurements your current measurement is just a a physical process that somehow changes the wave function. If you can fully describe this process (specifying the measurement Hamiltonian, interactions with environment, etc.) then determining the phase for future measurements is a matter of solving the equations. If however you suggest that some information is lost in your measurement, then all the bets are off.

Comment: So you are saying that if you know the process of measurement, then you can calculate $A$ using some rule?

Comment: @Riemann but what is *measurement* in your case? It is also a physical process - it somehow changes the phase, but you have no information about it, since you do not measure it.

Comment: It is not neccesarily the case that you don't know anything about the things that you don't measure. In the case described in my question, you measure only one number: the energy. After having measured this, you know a lot more than only the energy: you know exactly in what eigenstate the system is now. The means an entire function from $\mathbb R^3$ to $\mathbb C$ (up to some phase factor).

Comment: @Riemann you have to specify precisely what you know and what you don't know - as now your question is too ambiguous.

Comment: I suddenly realized that the phase factor does not matter after all, as you said: if there is a second particle, then the combined wavefunction is just multiplied by $A$ and if the particle interferes with itself later on then it also does not matter what $A$ is. So each value of $A$ gives the exact same physical situation regardless of what happens in the future.